# Get rows that are 5 minutes old

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana

I have a cron job that is executing my script every minute, and in that script I need to get rows that are in range from exactly 5 minutes to 5 minutes and 59 seconds. I am keeping the creation time as UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @Rulisp, will `interval 5 minutes` get rows that exactly 5 minutes?

Comment: try this
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `startTime` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND `startTime` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MINUTE)

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this Query in your CronJob

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE
my_timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```